# PerformancePoint 2010 filter calendar not default to the current date

Tags: performancepoint

I just migrated PerformancePoint from 2007 to 2010. Everything is working fine except the calender filter which is based on Time Intelligence Connection Formula. 
The first time the page is accessed, the filter shows the correct date which is the current date. Then I pick another date and close the page. Now if I open the same page again, the calendar displays the date that was picked previously instead of the current date. The result is the same even I open the page on another computer. It seems like the server remembers the calendar date selection. But I cannot find any server settings that may link to this problem. Appreciate if somebody can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

The last selection you made gets saved from PerfromancePoints persistence. You may want to check your connections to make sure they your filters are connected to the correct dimension or measure.

**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554986%28v=office.14%29.aspx)**:
The BIMonitoringServiceApplication service application provides the middle-tier business logic for the PerformancePoint Services instance and performs the complex processing for PerformancePoint Services features. It stores annotations, temporary objects, and parameter persistence (users' filter selections) in a database instance.

This article may help you find more information on the Time Intelligence: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2007/08/23/time-intelligence-post-formula-filters.aspx